# Mobile: Edit review queue, after 40/40 daily reviews, does not list time to next review any longer

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits, mobile-web, firefox

I've been reviewing suggested edits on the main SO for a while now. Until a few days ago, after filling the daily limit of 40 review decisions, there would be a message stating, in part, "Come back in X hours" (from memory).

This message seems to be missing since. This is what it looks like now:

[image: Full review page missing the time to next review.]

This is on Firefox 91.4.0 on an Android 10 mobile.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369567/no-more-thanks-for-reviewing-20-posts-from-a-review-queue

Comment: The message is back as of today: "Thank you for reviewing 40 suggested edits today; come back in 10 hours to continue reviewing."